# What is Google reaction to indexing redirect URLs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo, google-crawlers

i just installed a CMS script to make my website that it give me URLs like this :

```
site.ltd/index.php?page=ID
```

after some changes in URL, i used a .Htaccess code to remove index.php from URL. But this code do not remove index.php from original URLs. it just redirect index.php to none index.php.

For more understanding read this :
after i used this code, all of my post URLs still looks like this :

```
site.ltd/index.php?page=ID
```

But when i open this url, it will redirect to this :

```
site.ltd/?page=ID
```

**And main question is:**
in the source of my website, URLs have index.php, but after opening, transferred to the new address (without index.php) , Do not create a problem?

i mean this permanent transfer links (redirect index.php to none index.php for every links) do not make problems in decline in popularity and Google's robots crawl the site? and can google index my none index.php URLs and ignore URLs with index.php?

***And if you can: Give me a code that can remove index.php for ever in my URLs without redirect needed!***

Sorry for my English.ENG in not my main Language :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, if the redirection is 302 (temporary redirection process); then your site would be in trouble.

Google suggest us to apply 301 (permanent redirection) so that not only visitors; but also Search Engine Robots can also check the new url and index that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nasir. yeah i using 301